# Weapons for a tabletop game

Tags: technology, weapons

I'm making a race for a table top game with high tech weapons. What's a weapon that would shoot through people that isn't just a high powered cannon? Didn't have to be functional today because this is set far in the future.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on boardgames.SE.

Comment: A balista is like a big crossbow. That would do. But a lot of weapons could do the same thing with enough force.

Comment: Do you consider anything that shoots a projectile a high tech cannon?  Like a railgun?

Comment: I cast the last vote to close the question.  It's not a bad question, but it needs improvement to remain open.  (a) The fact that it's for a table top game is irrelevant, isn't it?  (b) Since your options are pushing a projectile through the body or burning a hole in it, what is it you're really looking for?  Is your question simply artistic, or are you looking to achieve a specific effect?  Please, take our [tour] and visit our [culture page](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) to understand us better.  There are amazing and creative people here, if you work with us.

Comment: Once you've improved your question, we'll happily reopen it for answers.